# Delegation in C++

Tags: c++, delegation

I am trying to understand delegation in c++. I read that "delegation is pointer to function", and i saw several examples, but unfortunately I cant get it. I have created code to try, because I thought that maybe while programming i will understand it. Unfortunately I didn't.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class person{
    private: 
        int age;
    public:
        person(age){
            this->age = age;
        }

        // virtual void changeAge(int arg) = 0;
};

class addNumber {
    public:
        int changeAge(int arg) {
            arg += arg+1; 
        }
};

int main(){
    person Olaf;
}
```

So based on this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568150/what-is-a-c-delegate) I tried:

```
Olaf = &addNumber::changeAge(10);
```

or

```
addNumber test;

Olaf = &addNumber::changeAge(10);
```

Both does not work. That means program is not compiling. 
I want to make person object to use `changeName` of `addNumber` class method to change the age of instance person class.

Comment: *"... I read that "delegation is pointer to function"... "* - Where did you read that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please define what do you mean by "_Both does not work._"

Comment: Your `changeAge` method needs to either static or you need to create an instance of addNumber.

Comment: it is completely unclear what the line `Olaf = &addNumber::changeAge(10);` is supposed to do. `Olaf` is a `person` while the rhs is most likely supposed to be a function pointer (it isnt). How is that assignment supposed to work?

Comment: You are trying to assign an address of value returned by function call to an object of unrelated type `person`. This has nothing to do with pointers to functions or delegates. You should get familiar with [C++ syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) first.

Comment: I am trying to force 'Olaf' to use `changeAge` metod of `addNumber` class. I don't want to use inheritance, because I want to learn delegation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's use a typedef for the function:

```
typedef int agechanger(int);
```

this makes a new type, `agechanger`, which will be used in code for passing the function instances around.

Now, you should give your `person` class a proper constructor, and properly incapsulate the `age` field providing a public getter. Then add a method that accepts a function as argument, function of type `agechanger`, of course.

```
class person
{
private:
    int age;
public:
    person(int age){
        this->age = age;
    }

    int getAge() const {
        return age;
    }
    void changeAge(agechanger f)
    {
        age = f(age);
    }
};
```

Then define a function that fits our type, inside a `class`:

```
class addNumber {
public:
    static int changeAge(int arg) {
        return arg + 1;
    }
};
```

Notice that the function is marked as [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400690/why-callback-functions-needs-to-be-static-when-declared-in-class) and returns the passed `int` incremented by one.

Let's test everything in a `main`:

```
int main()
{
    person Olaf(100); //instance of person, the old Olaf

    Olaf.changeAge(addNumber::changeAge); //pass the function to the person method

    std::cout << Olaf.getAge() << std::endl; //Olaf should be even older, now
}
```

Let's make and use a different function, ouside a class, this time:

```
int younger(int age)
{
    return age -10;
}

int main(){

    person Olaf(100);

    Olaf.changeAge(younger);

    std::cout << Olaf.getAge() << std::endl; // Olaf is much younger now!
}
```

I hope that having code that works is going to help you understand things better. The topic you're asking about, here, is generally considered advanced, while I think you should review some more basic topics of c++, first ([functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm) and [classes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm), for example).

Answer (score 2):

In [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) and later you have [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) (e.g. thru [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) etc...) and [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (that is, [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function))

But you don't exactly have [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(object-oriented_programming)) in C++, even if you also have [pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) to functions and pointers to member functions. But closures and lambda expressions are nearly equivalent, in power of expression, to delegation.

You should read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) then some good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book to understand these notions.