# Callback definition is incompatible

Tags: c++, arduino

I use [a library](https://github.com/LennartHennigs/ESPRotary/) which has these definitions

```
typedef void (*CallbackFunction) (ESPRotary&);
void ESPRotary::setChangedHandler(CallbackFunction f) { ... }
```

When I try to use the `setChangedHandler` function I get an issue that the definition of my callback is wrong.

```
#pragma once

#include "ESPRotary.h"

class MyUsermod : public Usermod
{
private:
  ESPRotary r = ESPRotary(13, 12);

public:
  void rotate(ESPRotary &r)
  {
    Serial.println(r.getPosition());
  }

  void setup()
  {
    // argument of type "void (MyUsermod::*)(ESPRotary &r)" is incompatible 
    // with parameter of type "ESPRotary::CallbackFunction"C/C++(167)
    r.setChangedHandler(rotate); 
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function needs to be defined statically when defined inside the class:

```cpp
class MyUsermod : public Usermod
{
private:
  ESPRotary r = ESPRotary(13, 12);

public:
  /* Callback function "static" defined */
  static void rotate(ESPRotary &r)
  {
    Serial.println(r.getPosition());
  }

  void setup()
  {
    r.setChangedHandler(rotate); 
  }
};
```

###### References

- [Why callback functions needs to be static when declared in class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400690/why-callback-functions-needs-to-be-static-when-declared-in-class)

Answer (score 1):

```
void rotate(ESPRotary &r)
```

This is not a function. This is a (non-static) class method. This is declared as a member of class `MyUsermod`, something that's completely different from declaring a function named `rotate()` is some randomly-chosen `.cpp` file, with no further context.

Class methods require instances of classes to be invoked for. The type of `rotate` is

```
void (MyUsermod::*) (ESPRotary&)
```

and not

```
void (*) (ESPRotary&)
```

and this answers the reason for the compilation error, and the type mismathc.

As far as how to fix it, there is no uniform solution for every instance of this issue. It depends entirely on how these objects are used in the rest of your program. The most flexible solution is to change `CallbackFunction` to be the correct type, and then decide whose class instance's method will be invoked in the code that invokes the callback.

Comment: Considering `CallbackFunction` is defined in an external library, it's probably not that flexible.

Comment: This is either poor library design, or it is used incorrectly. If the former, given that the library is free software, this shouldn't be a hard problem to solve.